# Como pasar un parametro en un link_to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

la pregunta es la siguiente , tengo un Modelo llamado publications , en este modelo tengo un atributo integer llamado :motivo  , lo que quiero hacer es que antes de que el usuario acceda a la vista del formulario de crear publicación haya una vista anterior con dos enlaces , por ejemplo en mi caso uno que diga "Alquilar(arrendar)" y el otro "Vender" , entonces el usuario al acceder a alguno de estos dos enlaces el parametro del atributo :motivo sea colocado automaticamente en 1 si es vender o en 2 si es alquilar, asi ingresando al llenado del formulario pero con este atributo ya prescrito . ¿Cual seria el formato de esos link_to? ¿tengo que agregar algún route igual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta (*Como pasar un parametro en un link_to Rails*), lo que necesitas no es una variable `motivo` en tu Modelo, sino una variable local (en tu ***vista inicial***) que pases al controlador, a través del Hash `params`, y finalmente desde el controlador hasta la vista de ***nueva publicación***.

```
#index.html.erb
<%= link_to "Vender", new_publication_path(:motivo => "1") %>
<%= link_to "Alquilar", new_publication_path(:motivo => "2") %>
```

Y que una vez lo tengas en el el Hash `Params`, lo guardes en una variable de instancia en la acción a correspondiente (por lo que yo entiendo es en `new` que lo necesitas):

```
#/app/controllers/publications_controller.rb
def new
    @motivo_recibido = params[:motivo]
    ...
end
```

Y teniendola en una variable de instancia puedes implementar la lógica que necesitas hacer. En la vista `new` puedes 
verificar que contenido tiene la variable con `debug`:

```
#/app/views/publications/new.html.erb
<%= debug @motivo_recibido %>
```

**Nota**: si realmente necesitas guardar esta variable en tu Modelo, lo puedes hacer también asignándole este valor, pero para implementar el envío de ese dato desde una ***vista inicial*** hasta una vista de ***nueva publicación*** no se necesita.

Comment: Muchas gracias justo lo que buscaba!